Determine if CLLocation output was a product of GPS, WiFi or Cellular checks
My understanding is that CoreLocation is a black box that when user gives permissions it outputs a location approximation.
Is there any way to check the location object to see if WiFi was used instead of the GPS ? Or similarly the Cellular data ?
One way that I had in mind was classifying the accuracy of the output assuming it would be GPS -> WiFi -> Cellular.
For example:
func inferLocationSource(location: CLLocation) -> String {
    let accuracy = location.horizontalAccuracy

    switch accuracy {
    case 0..<10:
        return "GPS"
    case 10..<50:
        return "Wi-Fi"
    case 50...:
        return "Cellular"
    default:
        return "Unknown"
    }
}

Are the accuracy or distance filters when initiating the manager affect the CoreLocation black box ?

Test your theory against reality. What did you discover?

How can I verify the input though ? Its a theoretical approach, any ideas ?

It's a black box. You said so yourself. You're trying to find out something you're not supposed to worry about.
